# Change login rules at Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a fresh project of Laravel 5.6 installed. I changed `create_users_migration`, added `$table->boolean('is_active');` field. Now, I want when user is trying to login, to check if `is_active` field is set to true.

I tried to rewrite standard `AuthenticatesUsers` method :

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

After `password` I added line `'is_active' => true,` , and now, when I press Log In button, it returns me an `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array` error.

I tried to just copy-paste this method in `LoginController`, but it gives me same error. Any ideas, or may be is here another solution?

Full `LoginController` code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'is_active' => true,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: please add your controller code for which you are having this error

Comment: create a middleware for this

Comment: @Sohel0415 I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are editing the wrong method. This method validates the request and "true" is not a validation rule, that's why you are getting the error.

Here is a simple solution. Override the credentials method on your `LoginController` as below.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $data['is_active'] = true;
    return $data;
}
```

So this way only active users can login.

You can also create a middleware and use it to send the users that have not activated their account to activation page.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is here a way of rewriting the `sendFailedLoginResponse` method, which throw `ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);` error? I want in case that user exists but is not active, to throw a "User has been deactivated" error instead?

Comment: @priMo-ex3m Not that I can think of. Since using this method, You can't say if the user's credentials are wrong Or his/her account is not active. For that you can override the `Login` method and write your own logic. For example first get the user with provided username and password, and then check to see if the user is active. That way you can know which caused the user login to fail.

Answer (score -1):

I did this for one project with a middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class isActiv
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->isActiv()){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('errors', 'Votre compte utilisateur n\'est pas activé sur le site. Veuillez contacter un administrateur pour résoudre le problème.');
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my route file `web.php` :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['isActiv'] ], function(){
```

And in my user model :

```
public function isActiv(){
    if($this->is_activ == 1 || $this->is_admin == 1){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: You ideally want to do this at login, not log them in and then just redirect them every time they try to do something.

Comment: Not obviously... and anyway this is the same working way... you can pass 2 middleware at the same time, one for 'auth' and the other one for 'isActiv'

Comment: If you're going to just redirect a user to a particular page every time they try to do anything, logging them in is a waste of time. Simple do an `Auth::attempt()` then check in the login code. Log them out, then redirect.